# Ho do I get rid of this error in react js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
<Input
    {...register('maxVisit', {
    required: '⚠ This input is required.',
     })}
     name='maxVisit'
     id='maxVisit'
     type='number'
     placeholder={selectedOffer?.maxVisits}//error here 
   />
```

No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: InputProps | Readonly): Input', gave the following error.
Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: InputProps, context: any): Input', gave the following error.
Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.

Comment: Are you using ```react-hook-form```?

Comment: Yes I am using react-hook-forms

Comment: I'm not getting your question. Can you please explain it

Comment: Try `String(selectedOffer?.maxVisits)`

Comment: I cannot display the placeholder with the value I want, I get an error on placeholder prop, because it does not accept selectedOffer?.maxVisits, I already tried to do parseInt(selectedOffer?.maxVisits), but I keep getting the same error.
Input', gave the following error. Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.

Comment: @Rashomon that didt it!!, thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Try matching propTypes. There might be a chance you are assigning number to string or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The TS error is that you are trying to pass a value of type number but `placeholder` prop only accept string values so you need to convert value of type number to string , before passing any value to a component ,

**TIP**:If you are using VS code , hover on the prop it will show you what data type it accepts you can pass it accordingly

```
<Input
    {...register('maxVisit', {
    required: '⚠ This input is required.',
     })}
     name='maxVisit'
     id='maxVisit'
     type='number'
     placeholder={String(selectedOffer?.maxVisits)}/
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try matching propTypes. There might be a chance you are assigning **number** to **string** type where you possibly defined your interface/propType for placeholder.

If you need number then change `string|undefined` to `number|undefined`. If you need string then use like this `String(selectedOffer?.maxVisits)` in placeholder.